# How to redirect all requests excepts few ones, using IIS Rewrite Module

Tags: c#, .net, iis, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to allow only few URLs on concrete domain, all other requests should be redirected to 404 Not Found.
I know how to redirect a concrete URL to 404, but I need like an inversion of this. How do I write such rule, what conditions should I use? Is there something like `not match` in rule syntax?

So, what I am currently using:

```
<rule name="Deny some request" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(.*)$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(.*)(\.domain_regexp_here.*)$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)(somename)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/Home/PageNotFound" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

But as there are now too many of such rules, so that I can even miss some of them, And that's why I want to simplify a bit, so that I allow some URLs, and redirect all others to NotFound.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found out an answer.   The key is `negate="true"` in condition :

```
<rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="url path" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" statusReason="File or directory not found." statusDescription="The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." />
            </rule>
```

If urls to allow more than one - add more conditions and put `logicalGrouping="MatchAll"` to `conditions` node.